# Using "SQLite.JDBCDriver" with Android

Tags: android, sqlite, classnotfoundexception

I'm trying to connect on an SQLite Database. Once, this Code was running fine on my PC. But now i get a "class not found"-exception.

Class.forName("SQLite.JDBCDriver").newInstance();

what could be the reason?
i allready installed different versions of JAVA, Android SDK and Eclipse.

at the moment i have installed: Java:1.7.0-b147, AndroidSDK: r12

thanks for your Ideas!
reto

Answer (score 0):

Is your class path setup correctly?

Since you run a PC, I assume you are using Windows, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378526.aspx) might be useful to you.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your hint! but i think i don't need any MS SQL-Sever-Jar file for the SQLite-DB. I tryd it. but was not working.... :-<

Comment: Just to make sure, in Eclipse, this is done by:
Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries Tab.
Click "Add External Jar" and then find your JDBC driver. 
And the link I pasted earlier is not unique to MS-SQL, it also states the case of SQLite, which is why I directed you to it ;) )